# Meteor on Windows XP / fiber.node failed

Tags: windows, meteor

Hy ..

I have installed Meteor successful on Windows XP. Creating a new project works, but running the project doesn't work. Application crashes with following error:

```
module.js:485
process.dlopen(filename, module.exports);
      ^
Error: no errorC:\Programme\Meteor\lib\node_modules\fibers\bin\win32-ia32\fibers.node
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:485:11)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
at require (module.js:378:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Programme\Meteor\lib\node_modules\fibers\fibers.js:13:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
Exited with code: 1
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

**Environment:**

- Windows XP (SP3)
- node.js v0.8.3
- meteor v0.3.7
- npm v1.1.43

I'm very thankful for every tip.

Comment: For reference: See [Meteor on Windows](https://win.meteor.com/) | An alternative way to harness Meteor on a windows Box ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, but on Windows 8 Release Preview. It seems the fibers package shipped with Meteor 0.3.7 does not work properly. Here's what worked for me:

First, I opened a command prompt with administrator rights and navigated to:

```
C:\Program Files\Meteor\lib
```

Or in your case:

```
C:\Programme\Meteor\lib
```

And then just reinstalled fibers:

```
npm remove fibers
npm install fibers
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Remove fibers and install it new helps.

Update didn't solved the problem.

Now the examples works and new created projects too.

Comment: On Windows 8, you can also set Node.js compatibility if you experience this again, although interesting to see that just removing and reinstalling it again makes a difference. I'll keep this in mind when I come across future problems with fibers and see if there's a bug in the development bundle...

Comment: On my WIndows XP box the node install process stopped due to missing program "vcbuild.exe".